# how to increase the size of virtual memory page file for the application data

Tags: c++, memory, virtual

Our application will allocate more and more application data as the time goes by, and is there any way to increase the virtual memory page file automatically based on the application calculation?

OS: windows 32 bit

Thanks

Comment: after verification, the WMI method can be used to retrieve and put the properties of the pagefile

Answer (score 3):

There is no point in doing this, since you are using x86 architecture and it has a limit of 2GB per application.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366778(v=vs.85).aspx

Extend the page file size to the maximum that you'll ever need, instead.  And, having the app consume memory linearly over time should force you to rethink your design, as no page file will help you escape the death of your program due to memory exhaustion.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. U are right for the application design. But how about the application running on the 64 bit Win Server. At the first deployment, the initial pagefile should be relative small, perhaps we have to provide the mechanism in the application.

Comment: Try not to rely on the pagefile to store your data.  Either rethink your design (yes, I'm repeating myself) or use some kind of 'external' database to do so.  If you KNOW that your data won't be in memory anyway, don't treat it as it would be.

Answer (score 1):

Just set it to System Managed size in the Virtual Memory options:

[image]

Comment: Thanks to Michael, But is there any way to do it with a C++ program? I have gone through the API, but have no idea.

Comment: my goal is to let the application decide the page file size according to its own requirement. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to stay away from trying to adjust the system pagefile within your program because the system pagefile needs to provide virtual memory not just to your process but to every other process that is running at the same time (including the OS). You might be better off creating your own memory mapped file and using it for virtual memory.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa366556%28v=vs.85%29.aspx