# postgreSQL 8.4. Error connecting to the server: FATAL: the database system is in recovery mode

Tags: postgresql, windows-server-2008-r2

I really need someone's help with this error in postgreSQL.

I have postgres installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. I'm trying to connect to it using pg-admin, some custom C# and another third-party tool that works on postgres.

Today, I've noticed that I can't connect to postgres. It gives me this error:

[image]

I'm no expert at postgres and this is a serious problem that I could not fix in a few hours. I've tried rebooting the server, restarting postgresql-8.4 service. the result is the same.

Update:

I've connected to the server with the problem via RDP.
The logs right before and after the problem contain the following information:

> 2014-01-29 18:47:46 MSK STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "TapeSegments"
>
> ```
>                         (umid ,clip_index, markin, 
>
>                         markout_duration, clip_name, 
>
>                         state, clip_filename)
>
>                         VALUES (:umid, :clip_index, :markin, :markout_duration, :clip_name, :state, :clip_filename) 2014-01-29
> ```
>
> 18:51:51 MSK LOG:  server process (PID 7844) was terminated by
>   exception 0xC000012D 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK HINT:  See C include file
>   "ntstatus.h" for a description of the hexadecimal value. 2014-01-29
>   18:51:51 MSK LOG:  terminating any other active server processes
>   2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK WARNING:  terminating connection because of
>   crash of another server process 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK DETAIL:  The
>   postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back the current
>   transaction and exit, because another server process exited abnormally
>   and possibly corrupted shared memory. 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK HINT: 
>   In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat
>   your command. 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK WARNING:  terminating connection
>   because of crash of another server process 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK
>   DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back
>   the current transaction and exit, because another server process
>   exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory. 2014-01-29
>   18:51:51 MSK HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the
>   database and repeat your command. 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK WARNING: 
>   terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>   2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this
>   server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because
>   another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
>   memory. 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK HINT:  In a moment you should be able
>   to reconnect to the database and repeat your command. 2014-01-29
>   18:51:51 MSK WARNING:  terminating connection because of crash of
>   another server process 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK DETAIL:  The postmaster
>   has commanded this server process to roll back the current transaction
>   and exit, because another server process exited abnormally and
>   possibly corrupted shared memory. 2014-01-29 18:51:51 MSK HINT:  In a
>   moment you should be able to reconnect to the database and repeat your
>   command. 2014-01-29 18:51:52 MSK WARNING:  terminating connection
>   because of crash of another server process 2014-01-29 18:51:52 MSK
>   DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this server process to roll back
>   the current transaction and exit, because another server process
>   exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared memory. 2014-01-29
>   18:51:52 MSK HINT:  In a moment you should be able to reconnect to the
>   database and repeat your command. 2014-01-29 18:51:52 MSK WARNING: 
>   terminating connection because of crash of another server process
>   2014-01-29 18:51:52 MSK DETAIL:  The postmaster has commanded this
>   server process to roll back the current transaction and exit, because
>   another server process exited abnormally and possibly corrupted shared
>   memory. 2014-01-29 18:51:52 MSK HINT:  In a moment you should be able
>   to reconnect to the database and repeat your command. 2014-01-29
>   18:51:53 MSK FATAL:  the database system is in recovery mode
>   2014-01-29 18:51:54 MSK FATAL:  the database system is in recovery
>   mode

So, basically, postgres is stuck on "the database system is shutting down" Is there anything I can do to "kick it", so to speak?

This is a development server with no clusters, nothing fancy.

Update 2:

I've tried to connect to the server with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\PostgreSQL\8.4\bin\psql.exe" -U postgres -l -h ntv.ncdev.ru -p 5433
```

It gives me the same error:

> psql: FATAL:  the database system is shutting down

Comment: Are you sure you are looking in the log files from the correct database instance and/or host? The message you get from pg-admin is inconsistent with the log stating 'database system is ready to accept connections'

Comment: Can you connect to the database using 'psql' when logged into the host server?

Comment: Make sure you're connecting to the same DB you're looking at the logs for. Also, is this a hot-standby streaming replica?

Comment: harmic. as stupid as it might sound I was indeed trying to connect to the remote host. I thought I had postgres databases on my local machine. It means I was checking the logs on the wrong server. It explains inconsistencies in log files.

Answer (score 1):

The exception 0xC000012D is "Out of **Virtual** Memory".

[Increase the size of your virtual memory paging file.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8469225/3952930)

[Source here.](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/4FC7E844.2010808@hogranch.com)